# TabControl items added with code have a different style than ones defined in XAML

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I have code that adds items into a TabControl:

````csharp
TabControl.Items.Add(new TabItem { Header = file.Name, Content = new MyUserControl(config) });```
````

The Tab Control:

```xml
                <TabControl Name="TabControl" SelectionChanged="TabControl_OnSelectionChanged">
                    <TabItem Header="Test"></TabItem>
                </TabControl>
```

[Expected selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLi9J.png)

[But Got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u38KQ.png)

When I select the items added using C# code (the second tab in the screenshot), the header gets covered by a block instead of an underline.

I tried searching and seems it's style-related but I can't figure out what to do

Edit: It seems to resolve itself after updating AvaloniaUI from 11.0.6 to 11.0.9